# How to set user account picture in fedora-22(KDE)

Tags: fedora, kde, accounts

I am using fedora since 2 weeks and facing a problem with user account picture. I have checked in 'System Setting' but there is no option for this.
I have also updated the system.

Can I set account picture manualy? Is there any option for it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add 64x64 image to your homedir:

```
~/.face.icon
```

or symply make symlink

```
ln -sv /var/lib/AccountsService/icons/[icon file] ~/.face.icon
```

Comment: Why can't I use a higher resolution image?

Comment: I want to set user account picture on logon screen (not on lock screen). Both pictures may be different.

Comment: have you read this: https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Account_Details? @VPN

Comment: @VPN, i have no such tab in this setting window. Possible bug (i have updated my system and setting becomes unavailable)